# Passar parâmetro com o ajax

Tags: java, ajax, primefaces

Minha aplicação recebe no primeiro campo do formulário um diretório. Através deste diretório vou listar os arquivos presentes no mesmo. Tenho um método que vai listar os arquivos de acordo com o diretório recebido por parâmetro. Após o usuário informar o diretório como eu faço o `ajax` informar ao meu método que lista arquivos qual é o diretório ?

O meu método que lista os diretórios:

```
public Collection<String> listarItensDiretorioOrigem(String query, String diretorio) {
        File diretorioOrigem = new File(diretorio);
        File[] arquivos = diretorioOrigem.listFiles();
        Collection<String> nomes = new ArrayList<String>();
        String nome;
            for (File arquivo : arquivos) {
                nome = arquivo.getName();
                if (nome.toLowerCase().contains(query.toLowerCase())){
                nomes.add(nome);
                }
            }

        return nomes;
    }
```

Minha página:

```
<h:form>
    <p:panel header="Informações dos Itens">
        <h:panelGrid columns="2">
            <p:outputLabel value="Diretório Raiz Origem: " for="diretorioRaizOrigem" />
            <p:inputText id="diretorioRaizOrigem" value="#{questItemController.questItem.diretorioRaizOrigem}">
            <p:ajax event="change" />
            </p:inputText>
            <p:outputLabel for="itemOrigem" value="Item Origem"/>
            <p:autoComplete id="itemOrigem" value="#{questItemController.questItem.nomeItemOrigem}"
                completeMethod="#{questItemController.listarItensDiretorioOrigem}" dropdown="true" var="bean" itemLabel="#{bean}"
                itemValue="#{bean}" effect="bounce" forceSelection="true" />
        </h:panelGrid>
    </p:panel>
</h:form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cara vc vai ter que fazer algo mais ou menos assim.

```
public Collection<String> listarItensDiretorioOrigem(String query, String diretorio) {
    File diretorioOrigem = new File(diretorio);
    File[] arquivos = diretorioOrigem.listFiles();
    Collection<String> nomes = new ArrayList<String>();
    String nome;
        for (File arquivo : arquivos) {
            nome = arquivo.getName();
            if (nome.toLowerCase().contains(query.toLowerCase())){
            nomes.add(nome);
            }
        }

    return nomes;
}
public void ajaxMetodo(){
    //todo 
}
```

Página:

```
<h:form>
<p:panel header="Informações dos Itens">
    <h:panelGrid columns="2">
        <p:outputLabel value="Diretório Raiz Origem: " for="diretorioRaizOrigem" />
        <p:inputText id="diretorioRaizOrigem" value="#{questItemController.questItem.diretorioRaizOrigem}">
        <p:ajax event="change" listener="#{questItemController.ajaxMetodo}" update="itemOrigem" />
        </p:inputText>
        <p:outputLabel for="itemOrigem" value="Item Origem"/>
        <p:autoComplete id="itemOrigem" value="#{questItemController.questItem.nomeItemOrigem}"
            completeMethod="#{questItemController.listarItensDiretorioOrigem}" dropdown="true" var="bean" itemLabel="#{bean}"
            itemValue="#{bean}" effect="bounce" forceSelection="true" />
    </h:panelGrid>
</p:panel>
```

Exemplo: http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/ajax/listener.xhtml

Comment: Deu pra ter uma base, obrigado.